# X11 window cuts off bottom 30 pixels of drawing (C++)

Tags: c++, graphics, x11

This is a homework assignment. Basically, we were given some code and had to run it through Bresenham's line drawing algorithm.

Everything works fine except that the lines are cut off at the bottom (about 30 pixels). The window is big enough, but it just displays white space at the bottom.

(If I make the window 30 pixels higher, all the lines are complete so the algorithm implementation is good.)

```
window = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), 0, 
0, 512, 512, 5, black, white);
gc = XCreateGC(display, window, 0,0);
XClearWindow(display, window);
XMapRaised(display, window);
```

Am I guessing the error is somewhere in one of these lines?

Comment: Do you implement some clipping ? Are you double sure to draw to the image bottom ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust No clipping and yes. I tried running the program on another computer and it worked fine (both Ubuntu) so I'm not sure what the issue could be.

Comment: Then this starts to smell like a firmware bug. Do a complete fill of the window with a straightforward double loop work ?